# Conditionally CONCAT based on helper column data using ARRAYFORMULA in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, concatenation, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

I have 2 columns of names (Name 1, Name 2) which I would like to concat into a single column.

```
[CURRENT DATA SET]    [FORMULA - CONCAT]
|   A   |   B   |     |      D      |
| Name1 | Name2 |     | Name1_Name2 |     
| Name3 | Name4 |     | Name3_Name4 |   
| Name5 | Name6 |     | Name5_Name6 |
```

This portion is working using my ARRAYFORMULA:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(
  IF(
    ISBLANK(B4:B),
      CONCAT(A4:A,B4:B),
      CONCAT(A4:A,("_"&B4:B))
  )
)
```

---

**Here is the issue:** Sometimes I need the CONCAT formula to put column B first, then Colum A (Example Name2_Name1).

**Objective:** The CONCAT formula needs to be conditional based on a helper column containing the list of valid name options.

**Logic:**

- If helper column matches CONCAT, CONCAT ColumnA_ColumnB.
- If helper column does not match CONCAT, ColumnB_ColumnA.
- If still does not match, leave blank.

**Expected Results using a helper column**

```
[CURRENT DATA SET]  [Helper Column]   [EXPECTED RESULTS]
|   A   |   B   |   |      C      |   |      D      |
| Name1 | Name2 |   | Name1_Name2 |   | Name1_Name2 |     
| Name3 | Name4 |   | Name6_Name5 |   | Name3_Name4 |   
| Name5 | Name6 |   | Name3_Name4 |   | Name6_Name5 |
| Name7 |       |   | Name5       |   |             |
| Name5 |       |   | Name8       |   | Name5       |
```

Is it possible to create an arrayformula to achieve these expected results?

Here is my Google Sheet: [Click Here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1X_HqcQMbifEg0AhHfSTC68KcemiShExtH6bLp1AdRp8/edit?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See if this works for you:

```
=ArrayFormula(IFERROR(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A4:A&IF(LEN(B4:B), "_"&B4:B,), D4:D, 1, 0), VLOOKUP(IF(LEN(B4:B), B4:B&"_",)&A4:A, D4:D, 1, 0))))
```

Comment: Wow! Very impressive. This works perfectly! Thank you JPV!